# Numpy vectorized operation involving different axis

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy arrays with three axis. I index the axis by n, the second by n' and the third by k. The first and second axis have dimension R, the third has dimension K. I have the variables with these following shapes:

```
R = 2
K = 2
w = np.random.uniform(low = 1,high = 3, size = (R,1,K))
lamb = np.random.uniform(low = 1,high = 3, size = (R,1,K)) 
L = np.random.uniform(low = 1,high = 3, size = (R,1,K)) 
Phi = np.random.uniform(low = 1,high = 3, size = (R,1,1))
epsilon = 2
tauy  = 0.5
```

I would like to calculate vectorized expressions that mix values from different axis. For instance:

```
for i_n in range(0, R):
    print(f'n={i_n}')
    Kn = (lamb[i_n,0,1]/lamb[i_n,0,0])**(1-epsilon)*(L[i_n,0,0]/lamb[i_n,0,1])**(1-epsilon)
    wsol = (((1/(1+Phi[i_n,0,0]*tauy)))**(1-epsilon)*(lamb[i_n,0,1]*lamb[i_n,0,0])**(1-epsilon)*(1/(lamb[i_n,0,1]**(1-epsilon) + 
                                                                                   (Kn*lamb[i_n,0,0])**(1-epsilon))
                                                                               ))**(1/(1-epsilon))
    print(f'Low: {wsol}')
    w[i_n,0,0] = wsol
    w[i_n,0,1] = Kn*wsol
```

How perform the operations above simply with vectorized operations on `w, L, lamb`, instead of relying on this loop?

As a reference, what I am trying to do is (where k = $\ell$ = 0 and k = h = 1 in the code above)

[image]

### Edit

Following @hpaulj's comments:

```
Kn = (lamb[:,0,1]/lamb[:,0,0])**(1-epsilon)*(L[:,0,0]/lamb[:,0,1])**(1-epsilon)
wsol = (((1/(1+Phi[:,0,0]*tauy)))**(1-epsilon)*(lamb[:,0,1]*lamb[:,0,0])**(1-epsilon)*(1/(lamb[:,0,1]**(1-epsilon) + 
                                                                               (Kn*lamb[:,0,0])**(1-epsilon))
                                                                           ))**(1/(1-epsilon))
w2[:,0,0] = wsol
w2[:,0,1] = Kn*wsol
w2 == w
array([[[ True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True]]])
```

Comment: What if you replaced the `i_n` with `:`, and took everything out of the loop?  The expressions are too long to read in detail (at least within my 30 second attention span).

Comment: @hpaulj It seems to work, thanks! Could you explain to me a little better or provide a reference of what's going on, and why this works? I understand the `:` will create a view of the array restricted in that axis, but it's not obvious to me why this works here. I'm not too experienced with numpy indexing and broadcasting (specially with more dimensions...).

Comment: In few words, whenever you have one or more expressions with arrays and there is some index that appears (in the same way!) in some or all of them, as was clearly your case, there's a good chance it can be vectorized.
You can ask yourself the following question: what information is actually provided by specifying those indexes? Every iteration of the loop is identical (`i_n` is ofc varying, but it appears in the same way in every array!). 
In fact, look at the analytical equation that defines Kn: the n index is dummy there, it could be essentially omitted without loss of information.